Spectral theorem related problem. Finding B where $B^2=A$
Is this correct?
Let $A$ be a symmetric n x n matrix with non-negative eigenvalues. Show that there is a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$.
My solution:
Since $A$ is symmetric and square, the spectral theorem applies. So there is an orthogonal diagonalization $A=PDP^{-1}$. If we make a matrix X that is a diagonal matrix with the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A$ (that are in $D$), then we have $X^2=D$. So if we write $B=PXP^{-1}$, then $B^2 = PXP^{-1}PXP^{-1} = PDP^{-1} = A$.
I know that $B$ not necessarily orthogonal diagonalizable, because the values in $X$ is not necessarily eigenvalues of $B$ and the $P$ doubtfully is the corresponding eigenvector-matrix (of $B$), but I have showed how to make such a matrix...

What if $A$ has negative eigenvalues?

@sudeep5221 my apologies, it is a typo. The task is non-negative, not non-zero... I will edit it. Sorry

If that's the case, then your proof seems correct to me.

If A has non-negative eigenvalues, then $X$ is indeed a diagonal matrix, and B a symmetric matrix.

The matrix $B$ is diagonalizable as $B=PXP^{-1}.$

@RyszardSzwarc do X necessarily hold the eigenvalues of B?

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $X$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $B(Pv)=\lambda Pv.$
